# Getting a navbar to appear on scroll with a white background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get my nav bar to have a white background as soon as the user scrolls down the website. But for some reason, I am not sure how to get the white background to appear on the navbar and mine keeps on disappearing as soon as I scroll

So my navbar appears fine with no background at the top of the page. Then what I need is as soon as the user scrolls down the page, it should just stick to the top of the screen with a white background over it.

Something like this : [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/nwV2r/)

But obviously i already have the navbar set up, i just need the background to appear

```
<body>
    <div class="parallax">
        <div class ="logo">
        <img src="Images/logo1.fw.png">
        </div> 

     <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Timetable</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Belt Rankings</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Classes </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Brazilian Jiu Jitsu</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Wrestling</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Boxing</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Yoga</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Women Self-Defence</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Treatments</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Kids</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>

          <div class="container">

        </div>





    </div>

    <div class="parallax1">
    </div>
          <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    // hide .navbar first
    $(".navbar").show();

    // fade in .navbar
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {

        $('.navbar-default').css({
          backgroundColor:  $(this).scrollTop() > 100 ? 
            'white':
            'transparent'
        })
        });


    });

});
      </script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #6D6D6D;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    font-weight: 300;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif, Arial;

    padding-bottom: 5px;
    color: #373432;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}


.parallax {
    background-image: url("../Images/back1.jpg");
    min-height: 1000px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
}

.parallax1 {
    min-height: 1000px;
}



.logo {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 40px;   
}

.logo h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 60px;
    letter-spacing: -5px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
    line-height: 6px;
}


.navbar {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  font-size: 13px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-top: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-left: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-right: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  transition: background-color 200ms linear;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
      background-color: #F8BD23;
      text-decoration: none;
       color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    }

    .navbar-nav > li{
  padding-left:30px;

}

.container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Quick question - have you altered the `overflow-y` properties of your `body` or `html` elements? If so, that interferes with Chrome's ability to get an accurate `scrollTop()` - it always comes out zero. I've struggled with that a few times before discovering the cause.

Comment: @arbuthnott no i havent , so i am not sure haha :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, you need to change:

```
...
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
  $('.navbar').fadeIn();
} else {
  $('.navbar').fadeOut();
}
...
```

... to ...

```
...
$('.navbar-default').css({
  backgroundColor:  $(this).scrollTop() > 100 ? 
    'white':
    'transparent'
})
...
```

You might also want to add in transition for `background-color` property of `.navbar-default` in your CSS, just like you did for your links:

```
.navbar-default {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  transition: background-color 200ms linear;
}
```

---

In practice, you want to wrap this inside a function that is called on more than just `scroll` event. Namely also on `load` and `resize` events, like this:

```js
var checkScrollBar = function(){
  $('.navbar-default').css({
    backgroundColor: $(this).scrollTop() > 100 ?
      'white' : 'transparent'
  })
}
$(window).on('load resize scroll', checkScrollBar)
```

Working example:

```js
var checkScrollBar = function(){
  $('.navbar-default').css({
    backgroundColor: $(this).scrollTop() > 100 ?
      'white' : 'transparent'
  })
}
$(window).on('load resize scroll', checkScrollBar)
```

```css
body {
  margin:0
}
body > div {
  background-color: red;
}
.parallax1 {
  min-height: 200vh;
}

/* 
 * all CSS above is just for for SO, don't use in project 
 */

nav.navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color 200ms linear;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="parallax">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="Images/logo1.fw.png">
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Timetable</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Belt Rankings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Classes </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Brazilian Jiu Jitsu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Wrestling</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Boxing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Yoga</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Women Self-Defence</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Treatments</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kids</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!--/.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax1">
    
  </div>
```

Comment: hi , so this does work but only when i scroll up :) i scroll down nothing, but as soon as i scroll to the top of the page it works for a split second :)

Comment: It should work. Something else you have is interfering with it or overriding that CSS. Without the ability to inspect, I can't help you more. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have uploaded my question with all my code from my site , but again i am not sure whats wrong

Comment: @RonTheOld, the whole point behind [so] is helping others. You need to create a snippet here, in the question, so your question and any answer to it will continue to help future visitors with a similar problem long after your website changes and no longer reproduces the problem. According to your comment above, something else is interfering with the script I provided. You need to show it in the question so a) I tell you how to fix it; b) others also learn how to fix the same problem. As of now, your question is not a snippet and it doesn't reproduce the described problem.

Comment: But that cant be the problem my friend, as i have shown u all my code for my example if u get what i mean? so if u ran that in a sinppet it would not work , but i will have a look

Comment: @Ron, I get what you mean perfectly. Now, you seem to link `js/bootstrap.js`. Do you have any idea how different Bootstrap 3 is from Bootstrap 4? You get what I mean? There are literally millions of possible reasons why what you describe is happening. Without the possibility to inspect the elements and use a console log I cannot help. Please tell me at least what version of Bootstrap you're using. I'm assuming it's `v3.*.*`?

Comment: @Ron, I made a snippet myself and figured out what the problem must be: you need to run this function on `load` event of your page, not only on `scroll` event. I guess you also want to run it on `resize`. See the example in the updated answer.

Comment: Using Currently v3. i will try and see what the problem is